# How to order stream merges?

Tags: xstream-js

I would like to merge two maps of the same source guaranteeing the order of the result. Here is a unit test that I would like to pass:

```
  const source = xs.of(1,2,3)
  const a = source.map(v=>v*10)
  const b = source.map(v=>v*100)
  const hist:number[] = []
  xs.merge(a,b).addListener({
    next: v=>hist.push(v),
  })
  expect(hist).toEqual([10,100,20,200,30,300])
```

Currently the result I'm getting is this:

```
Expected value to equal:
  [10, 100, 20, 200, 30, 300]
Received:
  [10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 300]
```

Comment: could you please post a jsbin? It will easier to experiment with it then.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert with `xstream`, so I can't propose you a solution. However, I think I can explain why you are getting the output you are getting as this is a common occurrence in other streaming libraries.

You have a merge of two sources. The `of` operator guarantees that it will emit the array values in order, the `map` operator guarantees that it will emits the transformed values in the same order as the received values, etc. But `merge(a,b)` does not guarantee that it will interleave value of a and b. It does guarantee that it will pass on the values of a in order, those of b in order, i.e. it guarantees only a partial order on the resulting output.

The question of, given some values to emit, which ones to emit at what time, and in which order relates to scheduling. I am not aware of `xstream` at this point of time exposing a scheduler interface , from which you could customize the scheduling of emission of values. Hence you are bound to the default scheduling.

Now back to why you observe those values in that order :

- merge(a,b) connects first to a

  - a emits immediately and synchronously all the values from the array
- merge(a,b) then connects to b

  - b emits immediately and synchronously all the values from the array

If you want to get the values 1, 2, 3 not emitted synchronously, you need to use another operator than `of` to do so, or construct your timed sequence explicitly, i.e. emit 1 at t0, 2 at t0+1, 3 at t0+2.

Comment: Thanks, @user3743222, for the explanation. I was thinking that the library might have a solution for this use case, which seems common enough.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a clue from [user3743222's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747219/2743458), using [`periodic`](https://github.com/staltz/xstream#periodic) to sequence the list.

Changing:

```
//const source = xs.of(1,2,3)
const source = xs.periodic(1).drop(1).take(3)
```

...produces in the console:

```
10 100 20 200 30 300
```

[ESNextbin](https://esnextb.in/?gist=8e2aa2d1d9bd6454b550b627fcb83a07) demo.

[`drop(1)`](https://github.com/staltz/xstream#drop) is one way to deal with `periodic` starting with `0`. One can alternatively use `++v*10` in the `map` function.

Comment: Thanks! I think the point of the source array is to contain some useful data. I initialized it with 1,2,3 to make the example simple, but my real situation involves mapping data records to status strings, so I can't replace the source data with a periodic.